Mock named exports with TS-Jest
Trying to mock spawn named import from child_process but failing to do so because it is readonly.
src/factory.ts
import { spawn } from "child_process";

class ComposeFactory implements ContainerFactory {
  constructor(type: string) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  async create(name: string) {
    console.log(`[${this.type} ${name}]: Creating.`);
    await spawn(
        "/usr/bin/docker",
        [
          "compose",
          "-f",
          `${process.env.DOCKER_COMPOSE_PATH}/docker-compose.${this.type}.yaml`,
          "create",
        ],
        {
          stdio: "ignore",
          detached: true,
        }
      )
      .unref();

    this.containerInstances.set(name, new ComposeInstance(this.type, name));
  }
  ...(delete function is about the same)
}

test/factory.test.ts
import { describe, expect, test, jest } from "@jest/globals";
import child_process, { ChildProcess } from "child_process";

import ComposeFactory from "../src/factory";

const spawn = jest
  .spyOn(child_process, "spawn")
  .mockImplementation(function (
    this: ChildProcess,
    command: string,
    args: readonly string[],
    options: child_process.SpawnOptions
  ): ChildProcess {
    this.unref = jest.fn();
    console.log("Correctly mocked spawn");
    return this;
  });


Tried mocking child_process, but child_process.spawn is different than
import { spawn } from "child_process";
Currently only workaround that seemed to work is using import child_process from "child_process" in all my source files instead of importing by name which seems silly. (Doable on a small project, but to me seems unfeasible on a large scale)
Is there a proper way to mock named ESM imports using TS-Jest?

How about import * as child_process, { ChildProcess } from "child_process"; in your test/factory.test.ts?

If you do that, you cannot mock spawn because it is read-only :D
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'spawn' of object '[object Module]'
(I presume you mean doing jest.spyOn(child_process, "spawn") after that)

You could achieve this by mocking the whole child_process module using jest.mock() instead of trying to just mock the spawn method, if that works for you:
import * as child_process from 'child_process';

import { ComposeFactory } from './compose-factory.ts';

jest.mock('child_process');

describe(ComposeFactory, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(child_process, 'spawn').mockImplementation(function (
      this: child_process.ChildProcess,
    ): child_process.ChildProcess {
      this.unref = jest.fn();
      console.log('Correctly mocked spawn');
      return this;
    });
  });

  it('should do something', () => {
    const compose = new ComposeFactory();
    expect(compose).not.toBeUndefined();
    compose.create();
    expect(child_process.spawn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

  console.log
    Correctly mocked spawn

      at src/compose-factory.spec.ts:14:15

 PASS  src/compose-factory.spec.ts
  ComposeFactory
    ✓ should do something (16 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.195 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.

